# Can I get the viewing angle of a pointcloud using SceneWidget in Open3D?

Tags: python, opengl, visualization, point-clouds, open3d

I would like to get the camera viewing angle of a pointcloud which is displayed using `SceneWidget()` whose scene is set like this:

```
self.window = gui.Application.instance.create_window("Open3D", width, height)
self._scene = gui.SceneWidget()
self._scene.scene = rendering.Open3DScene(self.window.renderer)
```

If I use `o3d.visualization.Visualizer()`, I can get it using `get_view_control()`, but cannot figure out how to get it using `SceneWidget`.

I tried to get the renderer object from `Visualizer()` thinking it could be passed to `rendering.Open3DScene()` but `Visualizer()` only has a `get_render_option()`

**UPDATE:**
Thanks @saurabheights for the answer. What I am trying to do is to load a pointcloud, rotate it, get/save it's view matrix and then for all other pointclouds, use this view matrix. So that I dont have to rotate the pointcloud each time. My intuition is that I could combine `get_view_matrix()` and `open3d.visualization.rendering.Camera.look_at()`. But I am trouble trying it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties of camera of SceneWidget are available via `widget3d.scene.camera`. Notice the class relationship:- `SceneWidget -> Open3dScene -> Camera`.

You should be able to get view matrix from

```
widget3d.scene.camera.get_view_matrix()
```

Note - You should rename `_scene` to `widget`, makes it easier to infer the class of the object.

Comment: Thanks! Now how can I set the camera to use this view matrix for the next geometry?

Comment: @ajktym94 - I am not sure on this. I have to spend some time building expertise of visualization module but dont think I will be able to do that at least for a month.